# Meaning of Modal Presentation/Stacking ViewControllers

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on a project which has multiple view controllers stacked in a navigation controller, similar to this:

https://youtu.be/yl2m4fDOLQo

I fear that I may end up stacking too many view controllers in one navigation controller. I understand that once there are more than 3 view controllers stacked in a navigation controller, the views are presented "modally"

First of all, what is a "modal" presentation? I looked it up in Swift documentation but I'm having some trouble understanding how it differs from the navigation stack. Second, if there is a problem, is there any way around it?

I'm new to this so help is much appreciated,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that once there are more than 3 view controllers stacked in a navigation controller, the views are presented "modally"

This is false. You can have as many view controllers in a navigation stack as your app needs, as long as the device has enough memory. View controllers in a navigation stack have a navigation bar (technically, this is part of the navigation controller), a back button and (hopefully) a swipe-right gesture that allow the user to go back "up" the stack. You add a view controller to the stack by calling `pushViewController(animated:)` and remove it by calling `popViewController(animated:)` on the navigation controller.

A *modal* view controller exists outside of the navigation stack. It does not have a navigation bar because it's not in a navigation controller. You are responsible for adding some way to dismiss the modal, such as tapping a close button placed manually in the view controller's view somewhere. You can even add a navigation bar instance manually and put a close button in it. You show a modal by calling `present(_:animated:completion:)` on the currently-displayed view controller and dismiss it by calling `dismiss(_:animated:completion:)`.